# PHP Fatal Error Failed opening required()

Tags: php, require-once

The full error is this,

```
  [error] [client ::1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): 
  Failed opening required 'src/core/AdminSystem.php' 
  (include_path='.:/usr/local/pear/share/pear:/Users/everardobarriga/pear/share/pear:/usr/share/pear') 
  in /Users/everardobarriga/smgadmin/src/controller/CmdLogin.php on line 3`
```

So I have an application I am trying to run locally and I have updated my `include_path` in php.ini, I am not allowed to modify any code I can only modify my `include_path` does anyone know how I can modify my `include_path` to get this app working?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add in `/Users/everardobarriga/smgadmin/` to your include_path, and hopefully that should fix it.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, I added this but the changes aren't showing up, I made the changes in the php.ini that showed up in phpinfo() and I restarted the apache server any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: Restarting the server would make the changes official; I'm not sure as to why.  I would probably make sure that you modified the correct variable in the `php.ini` and try restarting Apache again.  Lemme know what happens!

Comment: Hey thanks again, so it turns out that at the end of php.ini Pear decided to add an include_path that was actually overriding the include path I put in, it's still not working but for other reasons now haha anyway thanks for the help!